# Setting up an account and verifying the login in database PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have been having issues with logging in but the registration is working. I'm not sure whats wrong with it. I have provided images to show. This is the user I have created in my database, **username: user999 password: user123** [image] However I cant seem to log in with the password created.
When I enter the password, I keep getting invalid.
[image]

### Register

```
<?php 
include_once("connectDB.php");
$userErr = $passErr = ""; //error variables
$username = $password = ""; 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

// Check if username is empty
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
    $userErr = "Please enter your username";
} else{
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
}

// Check if password is empty
if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
    $passErr = "Please enter your password";
} else{
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
}

if(empty($userErr) && empty($passErr))
{
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT username, password, user_type FROM users WHERE username = ? ";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql))
    {
        // Bind variables
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $p_username);
        
        // Set parameters
        $p_username = $username; 
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
        {
            // Store result
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            
            // Check if email exists, if yes then verify password
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1)
            {                    
                // Bind result variables
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $user_type, $hashed_password);
                if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
                {
                    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password))
                    {
                        // Password is correct, so start a new session
                        session_start();
                        
                        // Store data in session variables
                        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;  
                        $_SESSION["user_type"] = $user_type;
                        
                        if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Administrator')
                        {
                            // Redirect user to admin page
                            echo "You are logged in!";
                            header("Location: libpage.php");
                        }
                        
                        if ($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Borrower')
                        {
                            echo "You are logged in! ";
                            header("Location: borrowpage.php");
                        }
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        $passErr = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                    }
                }
            } else{
                //account does not exist 
                $userErr = "User name does not exist.";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($conn);
} 
?>
```

### Login

```
<?php
//validation 
require_once "connectDB.php";

$nameErr = $userErr = $passErr = $confirm_passErr = $phoneErr = $emailErr = $typeErr = $err = 
"" ; 
$fname = $sname = $username = $password = $password2 = $phone = $email = $success = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
if (empty($_POST['fname']) || empty($_POST['sname'])) {
    $nameErr = "Empty fields";
} else {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $sname = $_POST['sname'];
}

//check username
if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
    $userErr = "Empty field";
} else {
    // Prepare a select statement
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    
    if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql))
    {
        // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $p_username);
        
        // Set parameters
        $p_username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        
        // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
        if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))
        {
            /* store result */
            mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
            
            if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1) {
                $usernameErr = "This username is already taken.";
            } else
            {
                $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
            }
        } else
        {
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again.";
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}

//check password
if (empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password2'])) {
    $passErr = "Empty fields";
    $confirm_passErr = "Empty fields";
} else if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['password2']) {
    $confirm_passErr = "Passwords do not match";
} else {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
}

//check phone number
if (empty($_POST['phone'])) {
    $phoneErr = "Empty fields";
} else {
        if (!is_numeric($_POST['phone'])) {
            $phoneErr ="Invalid phone number";
        } else {
            $phone =  $_POST['phone'];
        }
}

//check email
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $emailErr = "Empty fields";
} else {
        if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
        } else {
            $email =  $_POST['email'];
        }
}

//user type
if (empty($_POST['user_type'])) {
    $typeErr ="Please select a user";
} else {
    $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
}

//end validation 

//bind the variables 
if (empty($nameErr) && empty($userErr) && empty($passErr) && empty($confirm_passErr) && empty($phoneErr) && empty($emailErr) && empty($typeErr)) {

    //insert stmt
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname, sname, username, password, phone, email, user_type)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    //bind stmt
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssiss", $p_fname, $p_sname, $p_username, $hashed_password, $p_phone, $p_email, $p_usertype);

        //set parameters
        $p_fname = $fname; 
        $p_sname = $sname; 
        $p_username = $username; 
        $p_phone = $phone; 
        $p_email = $email;
        $p_usertype = $user_type; 

        //password hash 
        $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        //sql stmt excute 
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
            //if success
            $success = "You have been registered as a " . $user_type; 
        } else {
        $err = "Something went wrong";
        } 

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}

//close connection 
mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

```html
<body>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css">
    </head>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <h3>Login</h3>
                <div class="login">
                    <label>User Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $userErr; ?></span>
                    <br>
                    <label>Password: </label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                    <br>

                    <span class="error"><?php echo $passErr; ?></span>
                    <label class="logged">Register an account </label><a href="index.php">here</a>
                    <br><br>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
                    <br>
                </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

```html
<body>

    <head>
        <title>Register</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>

    <h3>Registration</h3>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <div class="register">
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" value="<?php echo $fname ?>">
            <span name="error"><?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
            <br><br>

            <input type="text" name="sname" placeholder="Last name" value="<?php echo $sname ?>">
            <span name="error"><?php echo $nameErr; ?></span>
            <br><br>

            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $username ?>">
            <span name="error"><?php echo $userErr; ?></span>
            <br><br>

            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>">
            <span name="error"><?php echo $confirm_passErr; ?></span>
            <br><br>

            <input type="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm password" value="<?php echo $password2 ?>">
            <span name="error"><?php echo $passErr ?></span>
            <br><br>

            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" value="<?php echo $phone ?>">
            <span name="error"><?php echo $phoneErr; ?></span>
            <br><br>

            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
            <span name="error"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></span>
            <br><br>

            <label for="user_type">Choose user</label>
            <select name="user_type">
                <option selected disabled></option>
                <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
                <option value="Borrower">Borrower</option>
            </select>

            <br><span name="error"><?php echo $typeErr; ?></span>
            <br>
            <span name="success"><?php echo $success; ?></span><br>
            Already a user? <a href="Login.php">Sign in here</a>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

?>

Comment: At at least on point in your code you're querying for name, password, user type, but bind name, user type, password. Your variables won't match.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular ah.. you meant in my login page?

Comment: Why do you have so much code for such a simple operation. You have been following that tutorial on Youtube, have you? Please find a better tutorial, preferably one that teaches you PDO instead of mysqli.